# Datatables::of() returning "data":[] on every page in pagination except first

Tags: json, ajax, laravel, datatables, pagination

I'm using `DB::table()` to get required data for datatables, than I pass received Collection to `return Datatables::of()`.
Data (for debugging purposes) is static - i'm getting first 10 rows using `->skip(0)->take(10)->get();` for every request. The problem is that for every page (except 1st) `Datatables::of()` returns `"data":[]`. I've checked using `dd(Collection)` - data is same...

Begin of content returned by Datatables::of():

```
{"draw":2,"recordsTotal":16684,"recordsFiltered":16684,"data":[],
```

What I've missed?

Comment: are you drawing datatable manually?

Comment: @DilipHirapara What do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is adding `->skipPaging()` to `Datatables::of()`